# CLR (c++ .net) as Addin to Dynamic NAV

Tags: c++, .net, dynamics-nav

I think this might be more generic, but in this case I try to create a c++ CLR to Microsoft Dynamic NAV.

If I do this in C# it works fine. C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VisualCSharp
{
    public class MyTest
    {
        public MyTest()
        {
        }

        public int AddTest(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add that to Dynamic NAV, I find it:

[image: Dynamic NAV Assembly List]

Select and press OK:

[image: Select list]

So far so good.

Then I like to do the same in C++ with a CLR class.

I start with creating a C++ CLR Class library and add the code for the test: (I did it inline here, just to keep code simple, but it does not matter if I separate it.)

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace VisualCPP 
{

    public ref class MyTest
    {
    public:
        MyTest() 
        {
        };

        int AddTest(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        };
    };
}
```

Do the same with this. In Assembly list it come up identical to the VisualCSharp addin, but it shows up as Processor "x86", but thats ok. I have C# that also do that (COM wrappers) and they also work fine.

However, when I press "OK" i do get an error telling me that it can not load the type "VisualCPP".

So, question is: What am I missing? I know that the CLR code is different as it is not pure managed (even using the depricated /pure compile option does not work), but is there some kind of setting or declaration that had to be done to make my class visible?

Answer (score 4):

As far is I know you cannot use unmanaged code in NAV.
You assembly also need to be signed - in you example the Public Key Token is null therefore it's not gonna work.

Situations like that I always recommend to create a wrapper dll to handle the unmanaged code though it (for example this is what Microsoft was done with the Office SDK)

I hope it helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, but my example where the Public Key Token is null, is the C# and that works flawless. But you might be on to something. I was just hoping not to make to many layers of wrapping. :)